# How to search for a word in entire content of a directory in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find, xargs

need to search for something in entire content

I am trying:

```
find . | xargs grep word
```

I get error:

> xargs: unterminated quote

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`xargs` expects input in a format that no other command produces, so it's hard to use effectively. What's going wrong here is that you have a file whose name must be quoted on input to `xargs` (probably containing a `'`).

If your grep supports the `-r` or `-R` option for recursive search, use it.

```
grep -r word .
```

Otherwise, use the `-exec` primary of `find`. This is the usual way of achieving the same effect as `xargs`, except without constraints on file names. Reasonably recent versions of `find` allow you to group several files in a single call to the auxiliary command. Passing `/dev/null` to `grep` ensures that it will show the file name in front of each match, even if it happens to be called on a single file.

```
find . -type f -exec grep word /dev/null {} +
```

Older versions of `find` (on older systems or OpenBSD, or reduced utilities such as BusyBox) can only call the auxiliary command on one file at a time.

```
find . -type f -exec grep word /dev/null {} \;
```

Some versions of `find` and `xargs` have extensions that let them communicate correctly, using null characters to separate file names so that no quoting is required. These days, only OpenBSD has this feature without having `-exec … {} +`.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep word /dev/null
```

Comment: +1 especially for `/dev/null`. It is a nuisance when the output format can vary, depending on how many files are matched... thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you mean the first option

grep recursive, for searching content inside files

```
grep -R "content_to_search" /path/to/directory
```

ls recursive, for searching files that match

```
ls -lR | grep "your_search"
```

Comment: grep -rin for recursive-case_insensitive-show_line_number

Comment: I want to be able to search in content of each file.

Comment: the first one returns any ocurrence in any file, specifying the file where the ocurrence was found

Answer (score 2):

If you have the GNU tools (which you do if the Linux tag is accurate) then you can use `-print0` and `-0` to get around the usual quoting problems:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep word
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), it's designed to be faster than `grep`, by skipping special directories like `.svn`, `.git` and such. It's a must have tool in the toolchest.

It's pretty close to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) for the common switches.

Ex. :

```
ack string
```

default is *recursive* mode in current directory.

Package `ack` on Debian & Debian likes (Ubuntu...).

---

```
$ apt show ack
Package: ack
[...]
Homepage: https://beyondgrep.com/
Download-Size: 70,4 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Description: grep-like program specifically for large source trees
 Ack is designed as an alternative for 99% of the uses of grep. ack is
 intelligent about the files it searches. It knows about certain file
 types, based on both the extension on the file and, in some cases, the
 contents of the file.
 .
 Ack ignores backup files and files under CVS and .svn directories. It
 also highlights matches to help you see where the match was. Ack uses
 perl regular expressions.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current directory you can use grep:

```
 grep -irl root .
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to find a string in files

Try `find . -name "*" | xargs grep -l "string"`

Comment: The error message from xargs ("Unterminated quote") means the OP has a file in . which has a quote in its name. Your line will croak on that as well. Like mu noted, you need a different termination.