# Grep a directory and return list with line numbers

Tags: grep, find, awk, xargs

I'm currently trying to learn more about bash scripting and all of that fun stuff, and I pieced together this little command:

```
find $path | xargs grep -n $pattern | awk '{print $1}'
```

While this DOES work, I was wondering if I was reinventing the wheel. Is there a better way to search through a directory, grep the files for a pattern, and return a list with line numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many `grep` variants implement a recursive option.
E.g., GNU grep

```
-R, -r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

You can then remove `find`:

```
grep -n -r $pattern $path | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

but this keeps more than the line number. `awk` is printing the first column. This example

```
src/main/package/A.java:3:import java.util.Map;
src/main/package/A.java:5:import javax.security.auth.Subject;
src/main/package/A.java:6:import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
```

will be printed as

```
src/main/package/A.java:3:import
src/main/package/A.java:5:import
src/main/package/A.java:6:import
```

notice the `:import` in each line. You might want to use `sed` to filter the output.

Since a `:` could be present in the file name you can use the `-Z` option of grep to output a nul character (\0) after the file name.

```
grep -rZn $pattern $path | sed -e "s/[[:cntrl:]]\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/:\1/"
```

with the same example as before will produce

```
src/main/package/A.java:3
src/main/package/A.java:5
src/main/package/A.java:6
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks much for that. Especially including the `sed` bit.

Comment: or pipe it to `awk` like this  `grep -rZn $pattern $path | awk -F: '{print $2,$1}'` and get pretty results! :)

Comment: Wouldn't the `-Z` and `-F:` not match here, @Jaypal ?  You would want to replace the \0 character explicitly: `grep -rZn "$pattern" "$path" | awk -F: {sub(/\0/,":",$1);print $1}'`

Comment: Ahh you are correct. It should be `grep -n -r $pattern $path | awk -F: '{print $2,$1}'`

Comment: @Jaypal the -Z is there to be able to recognize filenames with a : in the name itself. The last solution would strip part of files like "Report: January.txt"

Comment: Why would it Matteo, I tried this on my computer and got this - `[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -n -r "*p*" ./ | awk -F: '{print $2,$1}'
50 ./backup/GTP_Parser.sh
55 ./backup/GTP_Parser.sh`

Comment: @Jaypal GPT_Parser.sh does not contain a ':' character. awk splits on : how could it recognize if the : is part of the name? Or did I miss something? Try with a file named "test:file:with:.txt"

Comment: True, I assumed that the file name won't have `:`. Crap! :)

Comment: I was just being over-precise: I would assume the same, I almost never used the -Z flag anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, note that `xargs` only works if there are no whitespace characters or `\'"` in your file names. See [How to search for a word in entire content of a directory in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/how-to-search-for-a-word-in-entire-content-of-a-directory-in-linux) for an explanation and an alternative.

Also, always put double quotes around variable substitutions: `"$path"`. Without the double quotes, the shell expands whitespace and wildcards in the value of `$path`, so using it unquoted breaks if you have whitespace or wildcards in that file name. The same goes for `$pattern` (just for laughs, try leaving the quotes out and searching for `h*` in a directory containing files called `hi` and `hello`).

If your version of `grep` has the `-r` option to traverse directories recursively, you don't need `find` here. The `-r` option is present on Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X and Cygwin among others. Otherwise:

```
find "$path" -type f -exec grep -Hn "$pattern" {} + | awk -F: '{print $1 ":" $2}'
```

I fixed your `awk` call above, as well, so that it prints only the file name and the line numbers. I also pass the `-H` option to `grep`, to ensure that it always prints the file name, even if there happens to be a single file. This code assumes that your file names don't contain `:` or newlines; if they might, things get complicated, and you'd better either [rely on GNU grep's `-Z` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25697) or process the files individually:

```
find "$path" -type f -exec sh -c 'for x; do grep -n "$0" <"$x" | awk -v fn="$x" -F: 'print fn ":" $1'; done' "$pattern" {} +
```

Comment: This assumes that a file does not contain the ":" character

Comment: @Matteo Yes, or newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of the `grep` and use `awk`:

```
find $path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 awk "/$pattern/{print FILENAME,FNR}"
```

But using `grep` and `cut`:

```
find $path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nH "$pattern" | cut -d: -f1,2
```

Include the `-type f` clause so you don't get errors trying to search (in either grep or awk) on non-regular file types (symlinks, directories, sockets).  If you read from a pipe or a socket when another program is supposed to be, then you might mess up that program.

The `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` gets around having whitespace in the filenames.  It is not available on every UNIX system, but is on most.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do here.

```
find $path | xargs grep -n $pattern | awk '{print $1}'
```

To me, this translates to find all the files in $path, and search them with numbered lines for pattern $pattern and print the line number and the first word of the line that matches $pattern.  *(possibly not including $pattern itself)*

If that's the case, then you are slightly re-inventing the wheel.  You can do all of that directly from the find command, without the extra penalty of the xargs pipe.

```
find $path -exec grep -n $pattern {} \; -print | awk '{print $1}'
```

or remove the awk pipe for the entire contents of the line.

Using find's own `-exec` has the added benefit of gracefully handling whitespace in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

check the `-c` and `-n` useful options too.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do:

- avoid using so many pipes. Whenever possible, use a workaround. Instead of `find . | grep -n <>` why not use `-exec`?

  - You can also take advantage of Process Substitution.

Try doing the following:

```
awk '{print $1}' <(find $path -exec grep -n $pattern {} \;)
```

NB: This may work as is, or with a slight variation, depending on the shell and the version of `find` you're using.

Comment: Is there some reason for not using so many pipes or is it for readability?

I'm not too familiar with `-exec`, but I'll definitely do some reading then.

Comment: Process susbtitution won't work here, unless you know your file names don't contain whitespace or `\[*?`. See [How to search for a word in entire content of a directory in linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21169)